# Accessing parent folder html files using child folder html files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a question , wondering if it is possible or not !!!

Here Is a link that will prove I am not much of a noob!
[collegewebsite.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5whGfbIoM7KSXp5cHNiR01lb1E)

Now the question.

I am creating a project called Coffee Cafe for my tuition assignment.
I will be using a lot of css and html with javascript (only)

I have the project folders as shown below
[webfolders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoJrb.png)

now I open cafe.html
and put a link in it to go to a page say "homepage.html" in "links" folder above.

NOW CAN I DO SOMETHING THAT WHEN I CLICK ON A LINK IN HOMEPAGE.HTML (for eg. Back) I CAN GO BACK TO THE PAGE IN THE ROOT FOLDER cafe.html

There is a way to do it is to use the full path of cafe.html in homepage.html

for eg. 
`<a href="c:\cafe website\cafe.html">` <==this is full path in c: drive

`<a href="cafe.html">` <== this only works when the files are int the same root directory,,,

But in this example they are not !

Can I get a solution for this or shall I put all the files in the root directory as a last resort ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set your anchor tag href value to a physical location of the file. It should be relative or absolute url.

So instead of

```
<a href="c:\cafe website\cafe.html">
```

You should use `<a href="../cafe.html">Cafe</cafe>`
or  `<a href="links/homepage.html">home</a>`

When you put `../`, It goes back to one level back, that means when you use href=`"../cafe.html"` in a page which resides under the `links` folder, clicking on that will go one level back (which is root) and look for `cafe.html` file.

Comment: Thanks thats the thing I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your file structure:

```
/
/links/homepage.html
/cafe.html
```

To link from `homepage.html` to `cafe.html`, you would use:

```
<a href="../cafe.html">
```

The `..` denotes: "go back one directory".

You could even combine that, if you had a more complex directory structure. (e.g. `href="../../cafe.html"`).

Another way to link would be as follows:

```
<a href="/cafe.html">
```

If you start your url reference with `/`, you're saying to start from the root.